# SOA - What Internal Web Service Did Your Company Implement First?

Tags: web-services, soa

What internal web service did your company implement first? What did you learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the first movers was the "Customer base system".

The common authority for all customers in the company.

EDIT:
regarding the comment:
It did indeed open up for more SOA. It's about 3-5years ago (before me) and currently it was publicly known last year that the SOA helped the company switch from a 3years delayed system to a new one within a year.

Regarding other stuff:
Dont get me started on our SAP integration :S Thats 3 years old as well, and nobody is really able to debug or update the setup. Currently we are POCing webservice integration with SAP. Pheeew

Comment: What lessons did you guys learn from your experience putting this in?

Answer (score 2):

We just implemented a credit card processing web service that allows us to process transactions from a Delphi POS system and a Classic ASP web site.  Additionally, we are hoping to get it to work with a Java based IVR system.

The web service was written in ASP.NET (C#) and utilizes SSL encryption, XML, XSD validation and a load balanced web farm.

We have also recently implemented various utility services that do everything from address verification to creating orders in our ERP system.

Answer (score 2):

Our first web service was actually externally exposed. It caused us to think about security upfront...

Comment: Do you have any internal services now?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can get this conversation going. My company implemented a wrapper around the most common Active Directory look-up needs. I imagine this might be one of the most common things to do first in Microsoft/.NET shops.

Anybody implement a library of utility services? Write a facade to some SAP module? Wrap up some services for Human Resources? I'm curious to what people are working on.